# I stored the result in a variable. I got output with xml tags. I want to replace those tags with empty tags

Tags: ios, iphone, xml

How to do String replace method for a variable wish storing the data with including the xml tags. With out storing in a variable the string replacing method is working but my result is stored in a variable. Every time its keep on updated. That's why the string replacing method must be applied for that variable.

Sample strings:

```
<item>
    <Matkl>001</Matkl>
    <Text>Metal processing</Text>
</item>
<item>
    <Matkl>00107</Matkl>
    <Text>Miscelleanous</Text>
</it‌​em>
<item>
    <Matkl>002</Matkl>
    <Text>Electronics</Text>
</item>
<item>
    <Matkl>00207</Mat‌​kl>
    <Text>Monitors</Text>
</item>
<item>
    <Matkl>007</Matkl>
    <Text>Services</Text>
</ite‌​m>
<item>
    <Matkl>008</Matkl>
    <Text>Packaging</Text>
</item>
<item>
    <Matkl>01</Matkl>
    <Te‌​xt>Material Group 01</Text>
</item>
<item>
    <Matkl>00208</Matkl>
    <Text/>
</item>
<item>
    <Matkl>014</Matkl>‌​
     <Text/>
</item>
```

Comment: Can You show the example of your string and need more explanation for getting better responses

Comment: <item><Matkl>001</Matkl><Text>Metal processing</Text></item><item><Matkl>00107</Matkl><Text>Miscelleanous</Text></item><item><Matkl>002</Matkl><Text>Electronics</Text></item><item><Matkl>00207</Matkl><Text>Monitors</Text></item><item><Matkl>007</Matkl><Text>Services</Text></item><item><Matkl>008</Matkl><Text>Packaging</Text></item><item><Matkl>01</Matkl><Text>Material Group 01</Text></item><item><Matkl>00208</Matkl><Text/></item><item><Matkl>014</Matkl><Text/></item>

Comment: this is the result stored in a variable called result.Now i want to display the result with out those tags.Help me out of this problem

Comment: How can i eliminate those tags which are stored in variable to display the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right thing to do would be to use an **NSXMLDocument** to parse the string and get the text out, which you then can concatenate to a new string if you wish. Have a look here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Alternatively you could use an **NSScanner** to scan to the first occurrence of '>', then get all text until the occurrence of '<', then scan to the next occurrence of '>', and so on - you get the picture. NSScanner is described here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html